# Can security protocol default be set in the server?

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest

My Asp.Net applications make HTTPS requests using HttpWebRequest. My applications are hosted on Win 2003 servers and we recently disabled SSLv3 on these servers. In test environment where I have disabled SSLv3 as well, my applications work fine. In Production though, I am getting error.

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected     error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
```

After doing some research, I found that I am supposed to add something like

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Is there any Windows update I need to install or some settings I can change on the servers, so I do not have to do code change in my applications? I am trying figure out why my application fails in production but works in Test.

Comment: I believe that the server is closing the request, so try to contact the admin (if you're the admin, then please check _what is required by the server to communicate_.)

Comment: As a fix for Poodle, our systems disabled
    'HKLM:SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server'

and enabled 'TLS 1.0/Server'. We ignored 'TLS 1.0/Client'. When I enabled this, my application started working. 

If any one could explain why this started working, that would be great.